# Instantly disable Button on click

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick

I'd like to instantly disable a Button after clicking it, so a User can't click it twice in short succession and fire the OnClick_Event twice in a row. `btn.Enabled = false` doesn't seem to do the trick instantly. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Dennis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing is disabling it after a post back therefore your button will be disabled in the page that's rendered when the browser receives the response.

Do it on the client-side with JavaScript instead:

```
var button = document.getElementById('yourButton');
button.disabled = true;
```

If you're facing issues with posting back to the server, check out this article: [How to disable an ASP.NET button when clicked](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/10/06/how-to-disable-an-asp-net-button-when-clicked.aspx).

Comment: I was afraid this'd be an answer, how exactly would I call the OnClick Method then since this seems to overwrite the Serverside-OnClick.

Comment: Check this out: http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/10/06/how-to-disable-an-asp-net-button-when-clicked.aspx

Comment: Just being pedantic here, but there is no such thing as "Serverside-OnClick".  ASP.NET is generating some JavaScript for you which will hook to your <input> button which makes it submit the single <form> that ASP.NET makes use of to the server, making sure to send all the form data in the POST data.

Comment: Yes, that. Other than that, you may or may not be my personal hero because of your answer, thanks!

Comment: "you may or may not be my personal hero because of your answer" -- hah, why the ambiguity?  Am I or am I not? :p

Comment: Yes, yes you are, your complimentary Hero Medal & Gift Basket are in the mail!

Answer (score 3):

```
function disable()
{
var button = document.getElementById('<%= Button1.ClientID %>');
button.disabled = true;
}

<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="disable();">
```

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve this via javascript

```
function Disable(btn)
{
btn.disabled = true;
}
```

and add this to your button **OnClientClick="javascript:return Disable(this);"**

Answer (score 2):

You can handled it simply by this code.Suppose, here is a button named btnAdd.When you click this button it will be disable due to execute it's corresponding code.I mean due to post back it will be disabled.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
     btnAdd.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;" + GetPostBackEventReference(btnAdd).ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the `btn.Enabled= false` at the end of all the functionality in the Onclick Event of the Button. It will do the Required action.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I am still able to click it at least 5-7 times before this happens.

Comment: No, this is exactly what the OP said he did and it didn't work for him since this is done on the server-side, not the client's.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the button has raised on problem. You won't get the server side event fired. So better seek the alternative by hiding the button (and yes displaying some friendly error message 'working', 'processing' etc.). The work out on how to [disable asp.net button on postback](http://dotnetspidor.blogspot.com/2010/01/disable-button-in-asp-net-web-page-to.html) would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
YourButton.Enabled = false;

if(!YourButton.Enabled)
{
\\Your Code Here
YourButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

Hope this helps ;)