# disable button using javascript function in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, recaptcha

i am having a problem trying to disable a button, here is my javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var DisableButton = function () {
        document.getElementById("<%= LoginButton.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
    };
    var EnableButton = function () {
        document.getElementById("<%= LoginButton.ClientID %>").disabled = false;         };
   </script>
```

and this is where the button is located

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false">
    <LayoutTemplate>

        <%-- some elements here: text boxes, etc --%>

        <div>
            <p class="submitButton">
                <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In"
                ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

it worked in the other pages.. but here, i get this error

```
Description: 
An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request.
Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message:
CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login' does not contain a definition 
for 'LoginButton' and no extension method 'LoginButton' accepting a first argument of type
'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


Source Error:
document.getElementById("<%= LoginButton.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
```

additionally, i am calling these functions from google recaptcha events:

```
<div id="asd" class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="EnableButton" data-expired-callback="DisableButton" data-sitekey="site_key">
```

What am i doing wrong here? Did i miss something?

Comment: where is _here_? are you know that use two different controls _LoginUser.LoginButton.ClientID_ and _LoginButton.ClientID_?

Comment: @Grundy here means on that particular page. I only noticed it now, sorry.. but i corrected it already. and i still get the same error..

Comment: in other page you use same `<asp:Login ID="LoginUser"`? or just button `<asp:Button ID="LoginButton"`?

Comment: @Grundy just button.. tried lots of stuff, including changing `ClientIDmode` to `Static`

Comment: you need read about templates

Comment: you can try `((Button)LoginUser.FindControl("LoginButton")).ClientID`, possibly working without casting to _Button_

Comment: now i get this error instead, `CS1012: Too many characters in character literal` source: `document.getElementById("<%=((Button)LoginUser.FindControl('LoginButton')).ClientID %>").disabled = true;` 
is this where i should place it?

Comment: inside `<%= %>` placed simple c# code, so in c# string must double quote, but outside is js code, in js no matter what type quotes used for string, so try `document.getElementById('<%=((Button)LoginUser.FindControl("LoginButton")).Clie‌​ntID %>')`

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisableButtons()
    {
    document.getElementById ("<%=Button2.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById ("<%=Button3.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
    return true ;
    }
    </script>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return DisableButtons()" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

And more information use [Instantly disable Button on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868042/instantly-disable-button-on-click)

[Disabling Buttons within C# method](http://forums.asp.net/t/1623860.aspx?Disabling%20Buttons%20within%20C%20method)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         var DisableButton = function () {
            document.getElementById("<%=LoginButton.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
        };
        var EnableButton = function () {
            document.getElementById("<%=LoginButton.ClientID %>").disabled = false;         };
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to point `<asp:Button ID="LoginButton` that ID, I think

```
document.getElementById("<%=LoginUser.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
```

Comment: you cannot use directly id of server side control  in javascript.

Comment: @JaiminSoni you can with [ClientIDMode = Static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)