# stop or interrupt the user from logging in if reCaptcha is still unaccomplished

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, recaptcha

I'm trying to disable a button inside a login template from c# code-behind, I already tried doing it from javascript method on front-end, but I cant get it to work. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069313/disable-button-using-javascript-function-in-asp-net)!

Here's what I'm doing:

Javascript method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var resetCaptcha = function () {
        alert("Confirmation Expired. Please Answer Recaptcha.");
        PageMethods.disable();
        grecaptcha.reset();
    };
</script>
```

Where the function is called:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="site-key" data-theme="dark"
data-expired-callback="resetCaptcha" data-callback="DisableButton"></div>
```

The code-behind method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void disable()
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn = LoginUser.FindControl("LoginButton") as Button;
        btn.Enabled = false;

    }
```

And i also have this declared:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptMgr" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

But I still get this error when the captcha is succesfully accomplished:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'PageMethods' is undefined
```

Can anybody help me please? What am I missing?

Comment: FYI:  You are instantiating a button and then not using it:       `Button btn = new Button();
btn = LoginUser.FindControl("LoginButton") as Button;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to do what i want, (test the validity of the recaptcha before logging in), using the `OnLoggingIn` event instead of manually enabling/disabling the login button.

i was actually able to control a property of a front-end asp.net label from code-behind.

using this line of code:

```
(LoginUser.FindControl("RecaptchaRequired") as Label).Text = "Please answer reCaptcha";
```

where `LoginUser` is the ID of a `loginTemplate` and `RecaptchaRequired` is a label inside the template.

Just now, I realized i was trying to accomplish something using the wrong approach..

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do will never work.  You cannot access controls in the page via a PageMethod; it runs outside of the normal ASP.NET lifecycle.  But you can disable the control using JavaScript instead:

```
$get("<%= LoginButton %>").disabled = "disabled";
```

This only works on the client and won't persist on the server.  Note `$get()` is the ASP.NET AJAX method for getting a control, which `document.getElementById` does the same thing.

Comment: I tried it and now I get this error: `CS0103: The name 'LoginButton' does not exist in the current context` ... Please note that the _button_ is located inside a _template_. I'm sorry for bugging you, but I do not know what to do. Thanks.

Comment: I did use javascript.. `<script type="text/javascript">
     var resetCaptcha = function () {
        alert("Confirmation Expired. Please Answer Recaptcha.");
        $get("<%= LoginButton %>").disabled = "disabled";
        grecaptcha.reset();
    };
</script>`